# Dismounting MD RAID1 LUKS-encrypted volume with partitions

Tags: fedora, mdadm, luks, md

Fedora 29.  I created a 5TB RAID1 volume using `mdadm`.  I then encrypted the volume with `cryptsetup luksFormat`.  I then created `ext4` partitions on the encrypted volume.  (I did it this way so I can add disks to the RAID1 array, wait for them to sync, then remove the spares for offsite storage of encrypted snapshots.)

I had to run `partprobe /dev/mapper/md100` to get the partitions to be recognised by the running kernel, and they all showed up as `/dev/mapper/md100p{5..14}` (along with the whole-disk `/dev/mapper/md100` volume link).  I was able to mount and write to each partition without problem.

However, after `umount`ing each of the partitions, I cannot close the LUKS volume.  The `md100p*` symlinks are still in `/dev/mapper`.  When I try to `luksClose` the `/dev/mapper/md100` volume, I'm told it's still in use.  Trying to `luksClose` the individual partition links fails with

```
Command failed with code -4 (wrong device or file specified).
```

(Which doesn't make sense anyway, since they're not individually encrypted.)

`lsof` doesn't show any channels open to any `md100*` devices.

What's keeping the whole-disk LUKS volume in use, and how do I shut it down so I can stop it and remove it?

Thanks!

Comment: I found a way to do it, but I need to locate (and memorialise) the commands I used.